# Simple Python Program freezes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I wrote a little Python script that is supposed to run a webcam-preview and exit it when ESC is pressed (using Pygame).
It kind of works, but more often than not it freezes the screen..
Does anyone see any issues with this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from picamera import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
import pygame
import subprocess

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((10, 10))

    while True:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    camera.stop_preview()
                    return
main()
```

Comment: Edit: I put "camera.start_preview()" so far up to shorten the time until the preview appears. The same sceen freezes happen when the line is inside the main() function.

Comment: put many `print()` in code to see in which place/line it freezes.

Comment: btw: you don't need `get_pressed()` and `import subprocess` so better remove it.

Comment: did you try picamera without pygame - ie. [examples from doc](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html). Maybe it is problem with PiCamera or hardware, not PyGame.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I added some print() lines but once the camerapreview starts/freezes I cant see whats written behind it..

Also I removed get_pressed() and import subprocess..thanks!  

I tried the camera with another script that starts the preview, waits 5 seconds and then closes it again with no problems so I dont think its an issue with the camera itself..could still be an issue with the way the preview-function works..

Comment: I added some print() comments and uncommented the line that starts the preview so I can see whats going on. Aparently it freezes after _pygame.display.set_mode_

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a call to `pygame.display.flip()` somewhere in your game loop otherwise it'll act like it's frozen.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried to add it after "screen = pygame.display.set_mode((10, 10))" but it still froze. I dont even have to press a button for it to freeze after 2-4 seconds or so.. Could it have something to do with pygame.display.set_mode maybe?

Comment: It has to be _inside_ the game loop. It's what tells PyGame that the end of the frame has occurred.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questuion but where would _inside_ the loop be?  
After "while True"?

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Yes, the `while True` is your game loop and each iteration represents a single frame of your game. `display.flip()` tells PyGame that it's time to change to flush all the updates that have taken place to the screen. If, hypothetically, there was no notion of display flipping, you'd see the changes to the screen happen in real time which would look like flickering. As such, if you omit display flip, it'll just appear to do nothing, much like the way you are currently seeing.

Comment: I tried it but it still freezes. Or sometimes the image doesn't freeze and still is a live-feed but ESC wont work so I cant close it..  
I uncommented the line where it starts the preview so I can see whats going on "behind" it (added some print() comments) and most times it seems to stop after the _pygame.display.set_mode_ line